# ListView with footer in Android

Tags: android, listview, footer

In my Android application, I want to add footer to the `ListView`.

**listfooter.xml**:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
android:padding="3dp"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">    

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/getmore"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:gravity="center"      
    android:textSize="16dp"
    android:textColor="#D61E5C"
    android:text="Load More"
    android:textStyle="bold"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

This is my **main.xml** file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@color/white"
android:orientation="vertical" >
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/expecters_listView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/first_view"    
    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
    android:divider="#A9A9A9"
    android:dividerHeight="0.5dp"
    android:fadingEdge="none"
    android:paddingLeft="0dp"
    android:paddingRight="0dp"
    android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay"
    android:scrollbarThumbVertical="@drawable/scroll_thumb"
    android:smoothScrollbar="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

This is my `Activity` class, **MainActivity.java**:

```
public class BestExpectersActivity extends Activity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);
 expecters_listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.expecters_listView);

    footerView = ((LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE))
             .inflate(R.layout.listfooter, null, true);
    //after getting the result
   //set the direct messages to list view
        expectersAdapter = new           BestExpectersAdapter(BestExpectersActivity.this, remindersResult);
            expecters_listView.setAdapter(expectersAdapter);                                

            //set the footer                                
            expecters_listView.addFooterView(footerView);
 }
 }
```

List is visible with some items, But footer is not visible (not adding to the `ListView`).

Comment: Is the footer to be visible **always** or only **when you scroll down** to the last elements?

Comment: You should add the footer view before setting the adapter

Comment: It should be visible when we reach to the last item of the list

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to Add footer before `setAdapter` like following code.

```
//set the footer                                
expecters_listView.addFooterView(footerView);
expecters_listView.setAdapter(expectersAdapter);
```

I hope this will help you.